# How to fit properly a div with border inside a parent div with border?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass, styles

```js
class CardsDeck extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const cards = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
    return (
          <div className="App">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="card-deck" style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
                {cards.map((c) => (
                  <div className="card ">
                    Some text in my card
                    <div className="btn btn-primary sp-btn">
                      <a href="somewhere" className="btn">
                        Button
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <CardsDeck/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<style>
.sp-btn {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px !important;
}
</style>
```

I'm using bootstrap to create a section of cards in a React App.

Inside each card I have a button that occupies the entire width of the card div.

My card uses border and border-radius.

I created a sample here [Sandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-jackson-vu742?file=/src/App.js)

It is something like this.

[image]

**It looks ok, but if you take a look closely, you will see that the button is not touching the border of the card div**

[image]

**Is there a way to make the border of the button occupies the border of the card div?**

Comment: can you attach html/js/css codesnippet that you can reprodce in your description?

Comment: Hi @WilliamWang there's this sandbox I created here https://codesandbox.io/s/great-jackson-vu742?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i can see just two lines of text as a result in the sandbox

Comment: My bad, I didn't save it. Could you test it again?

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, my bad, you're totally right. I just added a code snippet to this post reproducing the scenario I described. Thanks

Comment: I would remove the `border-radius` from the button and add `overflow:hidden` to the card.